# folders disappear for a while after creating a new one

Tags: windows-7

Today a user in our company told me a strange story and so I took a look remotely on his machine (win7). He creates a folder inside a mapped network drive in a subdirectory. After that, if he go back to the root of the network drive, he will see only 1 folder. And after a while, say 2 minutes or 3 he can see all folders.

Do you have any suggestions what is happening here?

Thx 4 any answer,

tbol

Comment: Possibly SMB2 directory caching (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200(WS.10).aspx), or maybe a slow DFS share

Comment: none of those keys helped, any other idea?